# The space $\ell^p(a_n)$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

Let $a_n$ be a positive sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ and

$$
\ell^p(a_n)=\{ x=(x_j) : \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n} \vert x_n \vert^p < \infty\}
$$

with the norm $\Vert x \Vert = \Big( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n} \vert x_n \vert^p \Big)^{\frac{1}{p}}$.

> Prove that the space is a banach space.

I have already checked all the properties of a norm but I have no idea how to show that every cauchy sequence in the space converges.

Would appreciate any hints/help

Comment: The usual $\ell^p$ space is a special example (with $a_n = 1$) and is complete. Can you modify the proof of that and adopt into this case (or even use that fact)?

Comment: Try the usual trick of fining a subsequence $\mathbf{x}_{n_k}\in\ell_p(a)$ such that $\|\mathbf{x}_{n_{k+1}}-\mathbf{x}_{n_k}\|_{\ell_p(a)}< 2^{-k}$ and then set
$$ \mathbf{x}(m):=\mathbf{x}_{n_1}(m)+\sum^\infty_{k=1}\big(\mathbf{x}_{n_{k+1}}(m)-\mathbf{x}_{n_{k}}(m)\big),\qquad m\in\mathbb{N}$$ which converges absolutely for any $m$ (why?). You will get that $\mathbf{x}\in\ell_p(a)$ since $$\|\mathbf{x}\|_{\ell_p(a)}\leq \|\mathbf{x}_{n_1}\|_{\ell_p(a)}+1$$

Comment: Your $l^p(a_n)$ is actually $L^p(\mu)$ for some suitable measure space. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is just a corollary of the following fact:

Theorem: Let $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ be a measure space and $p\in[1,\infty)$,
then $L^{p}(\mu)$ is a Banach space.

---

For your problem: Let $X=\mathbb{N}$, $\mathcal{M}=\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$,
and $\mu$ be defined such that $\mu(\{k\})=a_{k}$. Clearly, $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$
is a measure space. Let $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a function.
By Monotone Convergence Theorem,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int|f|^{p}d\mu & = & \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int|f|^{p}1_{\{1,2,\ldots,n\}}d\mu\\
 & = & \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int|f|^{p}\sum_{k=1}^{n}1_{\{k\}}d\mu\\
 & = & \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}|f(k)|^{p}\mu(\{k\})\\
 & = & \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_{k}|f_{k}|^{p},
\end{eqnarray*}
where $f_{k}=f(k)$. Therefore, $l^{p}(a_{n})$ is precisely $L^{p}(\mu)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\{x_k\}_k \subset \ell^p(a)$ be a Cauchy sequence, i.e.
$$\forall \epsilon > 0 \: \exists \: N \: \text{such that} \: h,k \geq N \Rightarrow ||x_h - x_k||^p = \sum_{n}a_n|x_h(n) - x_k(n)|^p \leq \epsilon^p$$
from this insequality we get
$$a_n|x_h(n) - x_k(n)|^p \leq \sum_{n = 1}^M a_n|x_h(n) - x_k(n)|^p \leq \epsilon^p \tag{1}$$
for every $n$ and $M$, therefore $\{(a_n)^{1/p}x_k(n)\}_k$ is a Cauchy sequence of real numbers and for every $n$
$$\exists \lim_{k \to \infty} (a_n)^{1/p}x_k(n) = y(n)$$
Let us define $x \in \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ as $x(n) := \frac{y(n)}{(a_n)^{1/p}}$, taking the limit $h \to \infty$ in $(1)$ we get
$$\sum_{n = 1}^M a_n|x(n) - x_k(n)|^p \leq \epsilon^p \tag{2}$$
for every $M$ and $k \geq N$. Now we will prove that $x \in \ell^p(a)$, let $k \geq N$
$$\Big(\sum_{n=1}^M a_n|x(n)|^p\Big)^{1/p} \leq \Big(\sum_{n=1}^M a_n|x(n) - x_k(n)|^p\Big)^{1/p} + \Big(\sum_{n=1}^M a_n|x(n)|^p\Big)^{1/p} \leq \epsilon + ||x_k||$$
for every $M$ and by passing to the limit $M \to \infty$ we conclude. Taking the limit $M \to \infty$ in $(2)$ gives
$$||x - x_k|| \leq \epsilon$$
for every $k \geq N$ so $x_k \to x$ in $\ell^p(a)$